# Regex match - ignore regex rules though and match exact text

Tags: regex

I have many URLs that are somehow having the following text appended to them:

```
/example-title%5C';/
```

The URL should simply be:

```
/example-title/
```

So I tried this redirect regex:

```
^/(.*)%5C';/
```

redirects to

```
/$1/
```

But my software thinks that the %5C'; part is also regex and strips it out.

Is there any way to encapsulate the %5C'; part so that the "regex engine" doesn't try and process it as regex and just processes it as plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the value `%5C` is a backslash but it is URL encoded:

Try this:

```
([^\/]*?)\x5C\x27\x3b
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any resources or Google search times I could enter to learn more?

Comment: @Matt Glad to help, I highly recommend reading at `https://www.regular-expressions.info/`, and practicing at `https://regex101.com/`

Comment: Thanks, I also found this useful - https://www.urlencoder.org/ - you encode the character and then switch the '%' it gives at the front and replace it with '\x' for the regex rule.

Comment: @Matt Thank you the value `5C` is the hex value of the backslash we type the hex values like that `\x5C` but in the URL we type it like that `%5C` whenever a request comes from the client-side to the server-side any URL-encoded value in the URL such as `%5C` is converted to its original value which is a literal backslash \  then you have to match the backslash not its URL-encoded value, by typing a literal backslash \ or typing its hex value `\x5C`

Comment: @Matt You can also check `https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/`